# Arbitrary rotations in the plane spanned by two known quantum states

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Suppose I have two quantum states $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ that I know how to prepare from some fixed initial state, say $|0\rangle^{\otimes N}$ on some $N$ qubits with known quantum circuits $U_1, U_2$.

My question is, can I leverage this information to create a third quantum circuit that performs [arbitrary rotations in the two dimensional plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/598782) spanned by $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$? Such a transformation is perfectly well defined as my two states are simply two vectors in a complex vector space with the same norm and linked by a family of unitary transformations, with the geodesic path being the desired one that rotates $|\psi_1\rangle$ through $|\psi_2\rangle$, but creating a quantum circuit that performs this specific transformation seems rather tricky. I could do something with a [Grover-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) search but this is exponentially expensive in the worst case (which is the one I actually expect - in general my two states will be nearly orthogonal) and doesn't take advantage of the fact that I know my 'solution' state $|\psi_2\rangle$ nor will it give me the choice of rotation angle, only a number of steps I should apply my Grover iterate to approximate the desired angle.

This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14214) for creating arbitrary superpositions using 'coherent addition' seems applicable as does the linked paper but there one has two unknown quantum states which incurs a sampling cost. It is not clear to me if one can use the known preparation circuits $U_1, U_2$ in that protocol to gain, say, a deterministic quantum circuit that achieves the same thing.