# Superposition of circuits (d-level case)

Tags: quantum-gate, superposition

In this post: [Superposition of quantum circuits](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/superposition-of-quantum-circuits), the two states are qubits. Is it possible to generalize this question to two qudit case? ie, given quantum circuits $C_1$ and $C_2$ that generates $\vert \psi\rangle$ and $\vert\phi\rangle$ respectively, where $\vert \psi\rangle$ and $\vert\phi\rangle$ belong to a d-dimensional Hilbert space, is it possible to generate the superposition of them, $c(\vert \psi\rangle+\vert\phi\rangle)$, for some normalization constant $c$?