How to prepare a superposed state?
Given two arbitrary states, $|\psi\rangle\ \text{and}\ |\phi\rangle$ that are possibly unknown to the preparer, is there a way to prepare the superposition $|\psi\rangle+|\phi\rangle$ of them? (If it's generally impossible, would demanding orthogonality between them help?)

How are they given? As two separate registers? If so I think you can’t without violating the non cloning theorem. You’d get another copy of one of $|\psi\rangle$ or $|\phi\rangle$ with some nonzero probability, which is precluded by the no-cloning theorem.

Yes, on two separate registers. What if they're orthogonal?

possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11554/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14185/55, and links therein

No, you can't do it. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04955
Orthogonality by itself doesn't help either.
